# Stuck with Ansible and Azure Dynamic Inventories

Tags: azure, ansible, ansible-inventory

Truly straggling with Azure Dynamic Inventories in an Ubuntu VM running in Azure, any given help will be very much appreciated.
Looks like credentials have not been applied, created env variables to ansible azure secrets and related ids, but does not look like applying, or I might be reading the log wrongly

```
**Config Steps**

I created an Ubuntu VM, installed pre-requisites and Ansible

I created an Azure Service Principal and assigned rbac roles, exported the usual values to env variables

**Created the below files**

*azure credentials*
cat /home/azureuser/.azure/credentials
[default]
subscription_id=0000000000000000000000000000
client_id=0000000000000000000000000000000000
secret=0000000000000000000000000000000000000
tenant=0000000000000000000000000000000000000

*ansible.cfg*
cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory=/home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml
[inventory]
enable_plugins = host_list, script, auto, yaml, ini, toml

*inventory_azure_rm.yml*
cat /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml
plugin: azure.azcollection.azure_rm
auth_source: credential_file
include_vm_resource_groups:
- devops

*azure_rm.ini*
cat /home/azureuser/.ansible/azure_rm.ini
[azure]
include_powerstate=yes
group_by_resource_group=yes
group_by_location=yes
group_by_security_group=yes
group_by_tag=yes    


**From the VM launched**
ansible-inventory -vvvv -i /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml --list

***Reply and Error***
ansible-inventory [core 2.14.4]
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/home/azureuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
ansible collection location = /home/azureuser/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-inventory
python version = 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
jinja version = 3.0.3
libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Loading collection azure.azcollection from /home/azureuser/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection
Using inventory plugin 'ansible_collections.azure.azcollection.plugins.inventory.azure_rm' to process inventory source '/home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml'
toml declined parsing /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml with auto plugin: name 'azure_cloud' is not defined
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 293, in parse_source
plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/auto.py", line 59, in parse
plugin.parse(inventory, loader, path, cache=cache)
File "/home/azureuser/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 221, in parse
self._credential_setup()
File "/home/azureuser/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 242, in _credential_setup
self.azure_auth = AzureRMAuth(**auth_options)
File "/home/azureuser/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 1529, in init
self._cloud_environment = azure_cloud.AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD # SDK default
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 293, in parse_source
plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/yaml.py", line 114, in parse
raise AnsibleParserError('Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory')
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a
port.
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 293, in parse_source
plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/ini.py", line 137, in parse
raise AnsibleParserError(e)
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/azureuser/.ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
"_meta": {
"hostvars": {}
},
"all": {
"children": [
"ungrouped"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created one Azure Linux VM like below and installed Ansible to use Ansible dynamic inventory:-

Created Linux VM and installed Ansible with the commands below:-

> I have referred the commands below from the MS document here:-  [Get
> Started - Configure Ansible on an Azure VM | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/install-on-linux-vm?tabs=azure-cli#install-ansible-on-the-virtual-machine)

**Commands:-**

Ansible 2.9 with azure_rm module:-

> ````bash
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # Update all packages that have available updates. sudo yum update -y
>
> # Install Python 3 and pip. sudo yum install -y python3-pip
>
> # Upgrade pip3. sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
>
> # Install Ansible. pip3 install "ansible==2.9.17"
>
> # Install Ansible azure_rm module for interacting with Azure. pip3 install ansible[azure] ```
>
> Ansible 2.10 with azure.azcollection
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # Update all packages that have available updates. sudo yum update -y
>
> # Install Python 3 and pip. sudo yum install -y python3-pip
>
> # Upgrade pip3. sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
>
> # Install Ansible az collection for interacting with Azure. ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection
>
> # Install Ansible modules for Azure sudo pip3 install -r ~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt
> ````

Created credentials file by running the command below in my Ansible linux VM to authenticate with Azure service principal:-

```bash
mkdir ~/.azure
vi ~/.azure/credentials
```

Add the service principal values in the credentials file like below:-

```bash
[default]
subscription_id=<subscription_id>
client_id=<service_principal_app_id>
secret=<service_principal_password>
tenant=<service_principal_tenant_id>
```

[image]

> Export the service principal values by running this commands in your
> Linux VM and verify if the credentials are working by creating a
> resource group with ansible in your vm like below:-
>
> ````bash
> AZURE_CLIENT_ID=<service_principal_app_id> export
> AZURE_SECRET=<service_principal_password> export
> AZURE_TENANT=<service_principal_tenant_id> ```
>
> Run the below command to create resource group and test the
> credentials:-
>
> **Command:-**
>
> ```sh
> #Ansible 2.9 with azure_rm module ansible localhost -m azure_rm_resourcegroup -a "name=ansible-test123 location=eastus"
>
> #Ansible 2.10 with azure.azcollection ansible localhost -m azure.azcollection.azure_rm_resourcegroup -a "name=siliconansible54
> location=eastus" ```
> ````

**Output:-**

[image]

Now, I created a yaml file to use ansible inventory plug in and it got executed successfully like below:-

> I have referred the commands below from the MS document here:-
> [Tutorial - Configure dynamic inventories for Azure Virtual Machines
> using Ansible | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/dynamic-inventory-configure?tabs=azure-cli)
> to use the Dynamic Inventory ansible plugin

Create a dynamic inventory with the file name **myazure_rm.yml:-**

> ```yaml
>   - ansible-inventory-test-rg auth_source: auto
> ```

Run the below command to use the dynamic inventory plug in:-

**Command:-**

> `ansible-inventory -i myazure_rm.yml --graph`

**Output:-**

[image]

Find VM's hostvars with dynamic inventory:-

**Command:-**

> `ansible-inventory -i myazure_rm.yml --list`

**Output:-**

[image]

***Make sure your service principal has contributor or Owner role assigned at subscription level to perform Azure tasks.***